# Why doesn't this OpenCL kernel work?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, opencl, physics-engine

I am trying to write a physics emulator for Mac which uses OpenCL hardware acceleration. Right now, when I try to run my kernel with OpenCL, the debugger reports a SIGABORT at my `gcl_memcpy` line to get results from the kernel.

Right now, I have managed to simplify the code quite a bit and still get the error.  Here is my barebones OpenCL kernel which still causes a crash:

```
kernel void pointfield(global const float * points,
                       float posX, float posY,
                       global float * fieldsOut) {
    size_t index = get_global_id(0);
    float2 chargePosition = vload2(0, &points[index * 3]);
    vstore2(chargePosition, 0, &fieldsOut[2 * index]);
}
```

This literally just loads a 2-dimensional vector and then stores it immediately. And I know what you are thinking, but the problem is not an overflow error.  This equivalent code works:

```
kernel void pointfield(global const float * points,
                       float posX, float posY,
                       global float * fieldsOut) {
    size_t index = get_global_id(0);
    fieldsOut[2 * index] = points[3 * index];
    fieldsOut[2 * index + 1] = points[3 * index + 1];
}
```

What on EARTH is wrong with my vector code?

Also, incase it seems necessary, here is the gist of how I am creating the OpenCL context:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = gcl_create_dispatch_queue(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, NULL);
if (!queue) {
    queue = gcl_create_dispatch_queue(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, NULL);
}
cl_device_id gpu = gcl_get_device_id_with_dispatch_queue(queue);
char name[128];
clGetDeviceInfo(gpu, CL_DEVICE_NAME, 128, name, NULL);

dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
    cl_ndrange range = {
        1,
        {0, 0, 0},
        {self.pointChargeCount, 0, 0},
        0
    };

    pointfield_kernel(&range, (cl_float *)_pointCharges.clBuffer, point.x, point.y,
                      (cl_float *)_fieldValues.clBuffer);
    [_fieldValues getCLBuffer]; // calls gcl_memcpy
});
```

If I omit the `[_fieldValues getCLBuffer]` call, the abort happens at the end of the `dispatch_sync` call rather than at the `gcl_memcpy` call.

Comment: The obvious difference is that you're accessing 1 extra element of the `fieldsOut` array in the first kernel. Is it large enough to hold at least one extra element? If not, `gcl_memcpy()` may be running off the end of the array into memory that it doesn't have permissions to access. What happens if you just get rid of the last line of the first kernel. Does it still happen?

Comment: @user1118321 added an edit; it is not a run off issue.

Comment: I will add that this problem is happening on an NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M.

Comment: That's definitely odd! It almost makes me wonder if it's a compiler error. What happens if you write the code for `vload2` and `vstore2` inline in the kernel, just to see if it crashes after that? Also, do you have another card you can try it on? Maybe an ATI or Intel card?

Comment: The code runs fine on Intel integrated graphics. On NVIDIA, replacing the `vload2()` call with `(float2)(points[index * 3], points[index * 3 + 1]);` does the trick... Strange. For now, I can just use this.